# When I run the server, it gives me a message "Cannot GET /". What am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, get

I am trying to do a GET request in order to retrieve some images from my Cloudinary account. But when I run the server, I get a 400 status code on my UI with reading

> Cannot GET /

How can I solve this issue?

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const cors = require('cors');
const { json } = require('body-parser');
const axios = require('axios');


const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(json());

const { parsed: config } = dotenv.config();

const BASE_URL = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${config.CLOUD_NAME}/resources/image`;

const auth = {
    username: config.API_KEY,
    password: config.API_SECRET,
};

app.get('/photos', async(req, res) => {
    const response = await axios.get(BASE_URL + '/resources/image', {
        auth,
        params: {
            next_cursor: req.query.next_cursor,
        },
    });
    return res.send(response.data);
});

app.get('/search', async (req, res) => {
    const response = await axios.get(BASE_URL + '/resources/search', {
        auth,
        params: {
            expression: req.query.expression,
        },
  });
  
    return res.send(response.data);
});


const PORT = 7000;

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: your `BASE_URL` has /resources/image at the end of it, then the /photos route appends that again. I'm assuming you probably want to pull some value out of the `req` and append it get a particular image?

Comment: Yes, that is correct @Dave , and my "CLOUD NAME" , API_KEY, and API_SECRET are stored in a .env file on the server folder but for some strange reason it's not working.

Comment: how sure are you that the /photos route is being called? Perhaps comment everything out and just return 'hello there' as a sanity test. Also wrap your calls in try/catch to see if something is throwing. As written, you shouldn't get a 400 status, just '200' with data or no no data.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your server URL in browser you will get `Cannot GET /` because you don't have base route.

It's not needed in most cases, since you don't access your node server from browser, it just run's in the background.

You generally display your frontend (Angular, React) in browser.

But if you don't like the message you can add a base route.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World'));
```

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, but at least you won't get this error.

Comment: So my goal is to post my response to my react frontend which is already running concurrently with my backend server. For some reason, it's giving me a "Cannot GET" message and my BASE_URL is at the top of my server.js file